# How can create FloatingActionButton on the top of the keyboard in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, floating-action-button

How can create FloatingActionButton on the top of the keyboard but if keyboard is hidden, then in the bottom of the screen?

```
FloatingActionButton(
         modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(bottom = 2.dp, end = 2.dp),
         onClick = { visible = !visible },
         ) {
            Icon(
                 imageVector = Icons.Outlined.Send,
                 contentDescription = "Send"
                 )
         }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: ?? if the keyboard is hidden, how can something be "on top" of it?

Comment: added comment with examples

Comment: The FAB is only anchored to the bottom. Instead it's the Activity/Fragment space that is resized to include the Keyboard BELOW it. It's an Activity setting in its Manifest section ;)

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" will fix this. Add this to activity tag in manifest.